# animate a view from a particular point to fill whole screen and the re size it back to that point

Tags: android, animation

I Know how to animate a view to whole screen and animate back to its original size. here is the link to do this [Re sizing through animation](http://gist.github.com/rafali/5146957)

But the problem is that this technique works only when if my view is place at the start of the screen.

What i want is that if my view of height and width (50,50) is placed in center of screen below some button and i click that view it should animate to fill the whole screen and when clicked again it animates back to its original size (50,50)

Answer (score 10):

If you're using LinearLayout, try to set AnimationListener for this animation and toggle the visibility of the button appropriately. Set button's visibility to View.GONE [onAnimationStart](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationStart(android.view.animation.Animation)) when 'expanding' view and to View.VISIBLE [onAnimationEnd](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationEnd(android.view.animation.Animation)) when 'collapsing' it. Using RelativeLayout can be the solution for this problem too.

For animation:

```
public class ExpandCollapseViewAnimation extends Animation {
int targetWidth;
int targetHeight;
int initialWidth;
int initialHeight; 
boolean expand;
View view;

public ExpandCollapseViewAnimation(View view, int targetWidth, int targetHeight ,boolean expand) {
    this.view = view;
    this.targetWidth = targetWidth;
    this.targetHeight = targetHeight;
    this.initialWidth = view.getWidth();
    this.initialHeight = view.getHeight();
    this.expand = expand;
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    int newWidth, newHeight;
    if (expand) {
        newWidth = this.initialWidth
                + (int) ((this.targetWidth - this.initialWidth) * interpolatedTime);
        newHeight = this.initialHeight
                + (int) ((this.targetHeight - this.initialHeight) * interpolatedTime);
    } else {
        newWidth = this.initialWidth
                - (int) ((this.initialWidth - this.targetWidth) * interpolatedTime);
        newHeight = this.initialHeight
                - (int) ((this.initialHeight - this.targetHeight) * interpolatedTime);
    }

    view.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
    view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
    view.requestLayout();
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth,
        int parentHeight) {
    super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return true;
}

}
```

And layout XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Test"/>


<View android:id="@+id/centered_view"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#FF0000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This code works:

```
animatedView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!expand) expandView();
            else collapseView();
        }
    });

private void expandView() {
    expand = true;
    animatedView.clearAnimation();
    Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int maxWidth = display.getWidth();
    int maxHeight = display.getHeight();
    ExpandCollapseViewAnimation animation = new ExpandCollapseViewAnimation(animatedView, maxWidth,maxHeight, expand);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {    
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
    animatedView.startAnimation(animation);
    animatedView.invalidate();
}

private void collapseView() {
    expand = false;
    animatedView.clearAnimation();
    ExpandCollapseViewAnimation animation = new ExpandCollapseViewAnimation(
            animatedView, dpToPx(this, 50),dpToPx(this, 50), expand);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    animatedView.startAnimation(animation);
    animatedView.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro you almost solved my problem.I will vote it as answer when i'll get enough reputation